# Remove highlight in RichEdit

Tags: delphi, highlight, rtf, richedit

I am using the following code to highlight a selection of text in a RichEdit.

```
procedure TAFormatMain.BtHighLightTextClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  AColor = clYellow;
var
  Format: CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  FillChar(Format, SizeOf(Format), 0);
  with Format do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(Format);
    dwMask := CFM_BACKCOLOR;
    crBackColor := AColor;
    RiEd.Perform(EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, Longint(@Format));
  end;
  RiEd.SelStart := RiEd.SelStart + RiEd.SelLength;
end;
```

Can anybody tell me how to remove the highlight or what the colour value for "no colour" (equivalent to No Colour in Microsoft Word) would be.  I could not find any relevant information about this topic on the net.

Answer (score 2):

To rest the background color set:

```
Format.dwEffects := CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR;
Format.dwMask := CFM_BACKCOLOR;
```

See also: [CHARFORMAT2 structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883(v=vs.85).aspx)